# Lua 5.1 setfenv() table still loading in global space

Tags: lua, env, lua-5.1, lua-loadfile

I've been trying to work with setfenv() in order to load a chunk into an environment outside of the global environment but I'm having a little trouble. The following is the code I'm running:

```
-- main.lua
function SandboxScript(scriptTable, scriptName)
    setmetatable(scriptTable, { __index = _G })
    local sandbox = loadfile(scriptName)
    setfenv(sandbox, scriptTable)
    sandbox()
    return scriptTable
end

local function main()
    print(Singleton)
    local test = {}
    local single1 = SandboxScript(test, "C:\\pathto\\TestTable.lua")
    print(Singleton)
    test.Update()

    local test2 = {}
    local single2 = SandboxScript(test2, "C:\\pathto\\TestTable.lua")
    test2.Update()
end
main()
```

```
-- TestTable.lua
require("Singleton")
local test = {}

function Update()
    test = Singleton:new()
    print(test.var)
    test.var = "Changed"
    print(test.var)
end
```

```
-- Singleton.lua
Singleton = {}
Instance = {}

function Singleton:new()
    if(next(Instance)) then
        return Instance
    end

    Instance.var = "Init"
    return Instance
end
```

I'm expecting the output of this to be:

```
nil      --(First check in global table before running sandbox code)
nil      --(Second check in global table after running sandbox code)
Init     --(Initial value of the Singleton's var)
Changed  --(Singleton's var after we change it)
Init     --(Initial value of the Singleton's var in a different sandbox)
Changed  --(Singleton's var after we change it in the different sandbox)
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
nil
table: 05143108
Init
Changed
Changed
Changed
```

Indicating that the "sandbox()" is loading the table into the global space even though the I set the sandbox's environment to "scriptTable" using "setfenv(sandbox, scriptTable)" prior to execution of "sandbox()".

I've gone through the [Sand Boxes Example](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) mentioned in other posts but I'm still getting the same results. Any idea what I can do to load a script in it's own environment without polluting the global environment?

Comment: It seems that `require("Singleton")` executes `Singleton.lua` in global environment in despite of current environment.

Comment: @egor-skriptunoff You gave me an idea. It didn't solve the entire problem but made a little headway.
Doing the following in TestTable:
`local singletonTable = loadfile("C:\\pathto\\Singleton.lua")
singletonTable()`

Lead to the following output:
`nil`
`table: 051D3108`
`Init`
`Changed`
`Init`
`Changed`

Which appears to have still loaded Singleton into the global environment but at least kept the instance in the correct environment this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really polluting the global environment, what you see here is a nature of package system, that modules are cached and shared for every call to `require`, not depending on environment of calling function. That allows Singleton module to work, because if you will not `require` it, but do `loadfile`, it will load twice (and be very less singleton than expected).

So, if the real task is to load module *only once **per sandbox***, then you may swap `package.loaded`, `package.preload` and other loader state variables before entering into a sandbox. More info in `Modules` section of Lua 5.1 Reference Manual.

The solution with `loadfile` may be just fine, but if you plan to cross-require modules in complex module system inside your sandbox, this will lead to a big problem indeed.

Comment: You're absolutely right, reading the Lua documentation I was incorrect about how `require` works and it turns out that behind the scenes, for all intents and purposes, `require` is just `loadfile`. I've changed my code to use `loadfile` and everything is working perfectly.